# last item border doesn't work in Owl-Carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, owl-carousel

I am using **[Owl Carousel][1]** with **Bootstrap**. but last item border doesn't work in Owl-Carousel.

I want to add border on item hover. but right border is not display in last item.

## Example-1

When Owl Carousel **wrap** in bootstrap Grid `<div class="col-*-*">...</div>`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-9">
<div id="owl-example1" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl img-responsive" src="http://tinyurl.com/lwexfpf" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl img-responsive" src="http://tinyurl.com/lwexfpf" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl img-responsive" src="http://tinyurl.com/lwexfpf" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl img-responsive" src="http://tinyurl.com/lwexfpf" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl img-responsive" src="http://tinyurl.com/lwexfpf" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl img-responsive" src="http://tinyurl.com/lwexfpf" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    </div></div></div></div>
```

So, I get this. (Not work fine.)
[image]

## Example-2

**But**, When Owl Carousel **without wrap** in bootstrap Grid `<div class="col-*-*">...</div>`

```
<div class="container">
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl img-responsive" src="http://tinyurl.com/lwexfpf" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl img-responsive" src="http://tinyurl.com/lwexfpf" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl img-responsive" src="http://tinyurl.com/lwexfpf" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl img-responsive" src="http://tinyurl.com/lwexfpf" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl img-responsive" src="http://tinyurl.com/lwexfpf" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl img-responsive" src="http://tinyurl.com/lwexfpf" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    </div></div>
```

So, I get this. (work fine.)
[image]

Live Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/harnishdesign/zwd9uysg/18/embedded/result/

How can I solve border issue in Example-1 ?

Comment: When there are three pages in the carousel (which you can test by making the window smaller) the border appears correctly. This appears to be a rounding error in the sizing of the elements.

Comment: But, it is not work in desktop view(full window width).@RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1):

Add the piece of code

```
#owl-example1 {
   width : 850px; /* if you dont know the exact width mean set as 100.3% */
}
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/zwd9uysg/17/show/)**

It works fine in full screen mode

Comment: Thanks for answer. but, Here, I have work width bootstrap grid. So, I can not define their fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the right padding on the column containing the owl carousel:

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/zwd9uysg/19/**

HTML

```
 <div class="col-sm-9 owl-me">
```

CSS

```
.owl-me {padding-right:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below CSS. i have tested [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankushkk/ohqt8gj3/)

```
.owl-carousel .owl-item .item {
padding: 10px;
border-right: 1px solid #f00;    
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer {
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Comment: this example is good. but, actually, I want to add border on item hover. I have updated question. please check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with:

```
.owl-wrapper-outer {
    border-left:  2px solid silver;

}
.owl-wrapper .owl-item {
    border:       solid silver;
    border-width: 2px 2px 2px 0;
    margin-left:  -1px;
}
```

`margin-left` pulls the items over enough for the last right border to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the border-color to transparent and using an inset box-shadow instead:

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-item .item {
   border: 1px solid transparent;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #000000;
}
```